# How does the _.invoke method work in Lodash?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

## Background

From the documentation about the [invoke](https://lodash.com/docs#invoke) method, I read:

> Invokes the method named by methodName on each element in collection, returning an array of the results of each invoked method

Thus, I assumed that the following code would be synonymous, but this is not the case:

```
_.map(items, function(item) {
    return _.omit(item, 'fieldName');
})

_.invoke(items, _.omit, 'fieldName');
```

In this case, the `invoke` method produces an array of strings, while the map method returns an array of items with `fieldName` removed from each item.

### Questions

- How can one use the `invoke` method to achieve the same result as the `map` function?
- Why did `invoke` return the array of strings in this particular situation?

```js
var items = [{id:1, name:'foo'}, 
             {id:2, name:'bar'}, 
             {id:3, name:'baz'}, 
             {id:4, name:'qux'}];

console.log(
    _.invoke(items, _.omit, 'id')
);

console.log(
    _.map(items, function(item) {
        return _.omit(item, 'id');
    })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.3.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `_.invoke(items, function() { return _.omit(this, 'a') });`?

Comment: This snippet gives a different result for _.invoke (undefined) using lodash 4.17 
https://codepen.io/mran3/pen/RyRmqo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var result = _.invoke(items, fn, extraArgs)
```

Is equivalent to

```
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
  result.push( fn.apply(items[i], extraArgs) );
}
```

So if you want the same result as your map, it would be

```
_.invoke(items, function() {
  return _.omit(this, 'id');
})
```

The only difference is that `item` is not a parameter of the function, instead you need to use `this` as the function is applied *to the item*.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure to note which version of lodash you are using.

v4.11.1 uses [`_.invokeMap`](https://lodash.com/docs#invokeMap) when operating over a collection:

```
_.invokeMap([1,2,3], function () {
    console.log(this)
})
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer. It's actually more descriptive (showing "this" inside function) than the official documentation. I tried passing `function(element)` at first and got stuck with it.
This reply solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

`invoke` calls the function as an instance method.

For example,

```
[
(new Date()).toString(),
(new Date()).toString(),
(new Date()).toString()
]
```

can be rewritten as:

```
_.invoke([new Date(), new Date(), new Date()], 'toString')
```

It is roughly analogous to `map`, where `map` is passed a function, but `invoke` is passed a method of the instances.

If you really want to make `invoke` work for you here, then I guess you could do it like this:

```
var items = [{id:1, name:'foo'}, 
             {id:2, name:'bar'}, 
             {id:3, name:'baz'}, 
             {id:4, name:'qux'}];
_.invoke(items, function() { return _.omit(this, 'id') });
// => [Object {name="foo"}, Object {name="bar"}, Object {name="baz"}, Object {name="qux"}]
```

but you shouldn't do that. Just use `map`.

Answer (score 2):

As [Joe Frambach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253312/joe-frambach) suggested, [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) is better suited for this.

```
var collection = [
    { id:1, name:'foo' },
    { id:2, name:'bar' },
    { id:3, name:'baz' },
    { id:4, name:'qux' }
];

_.map(collection, _.ary(_.partialRight(_.omit, 'id'), 1));
// → 
// [
//   { name: 'foo' },
//   { name: 'bar' },
//   { name: 'baz' },
//   { name: 'qux' }
// ]
```