# Return an array with the result of calling a method from underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I'm trying to recreate the functionality of the underscore _.invoke for learning purposes and I would like to really understand how it works as it seems to be something not too complicated.

The exercise is asking me to return an array with the result of calling "a" method to it. Ok, so here we start.

```js
_.invoke = function (collection, methodName) {
  let result = []; 
  // debugger;
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) { // check if collection is an array.
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) { // iterate over collection
      result.push(Array.prototype.methodName.call(collection[i]));
    }
  }
  console.log('result:', result);
  return result;
};
```

I don't know exactly what *method* is being past to `methodName` nor if it has any extra arguments to be forwarded (this I understand it would be used in case I'd use a method that requires args like `.reduce` for instance if I'm not wrong).

As I understand, when I use the `.call` method on `methodName`, it should return (push) the iterated element with the "function" applied onto it. Obviously there is something not right, I have used the debugger to see what it does on each step and once it runs the loop and arrives to the *call*, it quits the loop and runs to check whatever it is it does in the config file of the test.

I get this message in the error log of the HTML file:

```js
_.invoke(mocks.arr, 'testCall').should.eql(mocks.arr);
_.invoke(mocks.obj, 'testCall').should.eql(mocks.objValuesArr);
```

```js
argsArr = [mocks.arr, mocks.obj];
_.invoke(mocks.arr, 'testArgs', mocks.arr, mocks.obj);
called.should.be.true;
called = false;
argsArr = [mocks.obj, mocks.arr];
_.invoke(mocks.obj, 'testArgs', mocks.obj, mocks.arr);
called.should.be.true;
```

The *this*, *thisArg* and such are still a little hard for me to understand, can someone explain to me what am I missing here..?

Comment: What does `testCall` refer to?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to write your own implementation of lodash's invoke? https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#invoke

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888777/how-does-the-invoke-method-work-in-lodash

Comment: @lucasvw yes and not exactly, i'm a JS student and I should learn the ins and outs of how things are made, which is where I'm struggling to understand the how.

Comment: @jarmod thanks for the link, I have already tried that with no success, there is something else that I'm not grasping

Comment: How closely are you wanting to copy the functionality that lodash provides? One thing to note is that the second argument, `methodName`, can be a `function` or a "path of the method to invoke". The former is pretty easy to implement, the latter likely uses other lodash functionality to determine what method to call (see https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#get)

Comment: It's not lodash library I'm using but underscore. Determining wether `methodName` is a `function` or a path to one was the tricky part. It ended up being the latter! Hence using `_.map` was a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some digging, trial and error, I was totally wrong about my approach to the exercise, so I had to re-make the whole thing.

```js
_.invoke = function (collection, methodName) {
  // Spread all arguments into a variable.
  let args = [...arguments];
  // Since the arguments have been all passed to args, we don't need to call them as we normally would.
  // Use an already defined function (_.map) with an iteratee to be passed as method.
  return _.map(args[0], function (value) {
    // Return the iterated value passed through the function of _.map
    // and apply the rest of arguments to the element with the function from _.map if there are any.
    return value[args[1]].apply(value, args.slice(2));
  });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about underscore.js, but I'm pretty sure _ isn't defined at all, so maybe do `window._.invoke = ...` instead to properly define it.